# Set selected language after login

Tags: php, laravel

I have a login form with select option with languages. So, in my form I have this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="language">
<option>Choose language...</option>
@foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)

<option value="{{$localeCode}}" @if(App::getLocale() === $localeCode) selected="selected" @endif>
    {{$properties["native"]}}
</option>

@endforeach
</select>
```

After login I try to set it in authenticated method:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {

        App::setLocale(Input::get('language'));
        $user->countOfLogins++;

        $user->save();
    }
```

But I always get the English language. Btw, when I do `dd(Input::get('language')`, I get `de` or whatever... Also, I use this package https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: does the prefix of english is present in your URL?

Comment: It's not beacuse I've set `'hideDefaultLocaleInURL'  => true,` ... But usually it is presented...

Comment: hmm, it seems like the seLocale method consider the value present in the url before the one that we set manually